# ios7 UINavigationBar in screenshot becomes black

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I am porting my project from ios6 to 7. I have a function to make a screenshot of my view which has a navigation bar, on ios6 it works fine, but on ios7 bar in screenshot becomes black.

As you can see from the image, I have a navigation bar at top, a tool bar in the middle and a tab bar at the bottom,

Screen shot code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

[image]
[image]